Why are the prediction intervals for my DNN regression model horizontal lines?
I am working on developing prediction intervals for deep reinforcement learning. Therefore, I am following the instructions given over here. I ran a small example using a simple deep-learning model to develop prediction intervals. However, I see that the predictions are horizontal lines.
As instructed in the link, I developed a probabilistic model by forcing my neural network to output a mean and a variance -
    def forward(self, x):
        mean = self.mean(x)
        var = self.var(x)
        return self.selu(mean), torch.exp(var)

Then, I sampled from the network -
# Repeat mean and var num_samples times
mean = mean.repeat(num_samples, num_samples)
var = var.repeat(num_samples, num_samples)

# Sample from the predicted distributions
samples = mean + torch.randn_like(mean) * torch.sqrt(var)

Then I took its quantiles -
lower_bound, upper_bound = torch.quantile(samples, torch.tensor([0.025, 0.975]), dim=1)


Here is my code -
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Check if GPU is available and set the device accordingly
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Define the dataset
x = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 100).view(100, 1).to(device)
y = (3 * x + 1 + torch.randn(x.size()) * 0.2).to(device)

# Define the model
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_output):
        super().__init__()
        self.mean = nn.Linear(n_feature, n_output)  # Linear layer for mean
        self.var = nn.Linear(n_feature, n_output)  # Linear layer for variance
        self.selu = nn.SELU()  # Add non-linearity

    def forward(self, x):
        mean = self.mean(x)
        var = self.var(x)
        return self.selu(mean), torch.exp(var)

# Create an instance of Net and transfer it to the device
net = Net(n_feature=1, n_output=1).to(device)

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

# Training loop
for t in range(500000):
    mean, var = net(x)
    loss = torch.mean((y - mean)**2 / var + torch.log(var))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if t % 20 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {t} | Loss: {loss.item()}")

# Assume we have some test data
x_test = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 100).view(100, 1).to(device)

# Get the predicted mean and variance
mean, var = net(x_test)

# Rest of your code for prediction intervals and plotting


num_samples = 100
# Assume we have some test data
x_test = torch.linspace(-1, 1, 100).view(100, 1)

# Get the predicted mean and variance
mean, var = net(x_test)

# Repeat mean and var num_samples times
mean = mean.repeat(num_samples, num_samples)
var = var.repeat(num_samples, num_samples)

# Sample from the predicted distributions
samples = mean + torch.randn_like(mean) * torch.sqrt(var)
# Transpose samples so that quantiles are calculated for each test point separately
samples = samples.t()

# Calculate prediction intervals
lower_bound, upper_bound = torch.quantile(samples, torch.tensor([0.025, 0.975]), dim=1)
x_lower_bound = []
x_upper_bound = []
# Print prediction intervals
for i in range(len(x_test)):

    # print(f"Prediction interval for i = {i},x={x_test[i]}: [{lower_bound[i]}, {upper_bound[i]}]")
    print(f"Prediction interval for i = {i}")
    x_lower_bound.append(lower_bound[i].detach().numpy())
    x_upper_bound.append(upper_bound[i].detach().numpy())

plt.plot(x, y, label = 'real values')
plt.plot(x, net(x)[0].detach().numpy(), label = 'predictions')
plt.plot(x, x_lower_bound, label = 'lower bound')
plt.plot(x, x_upper_bound, label = 'upper bound')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

As seen in the image below, my prediction intervals come out to be horizontal lines. Is there a way to get a tighter bound -

